# Schedule publishing

Tags: publishing

Whenever I try to schedule the publishing of an item, it is not getting published at that scheduled time. Instead, it is getting published after 4-5 minutes, sometimes it takes more.

Is there any reason behind this? I am using the `OOTB Sitecore` schedule publishing module functionality for scheduled publishing.

Comment: If you need to publish at a very specific time, you migth want to check this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/2124/237

Answer (score 2):

You have something called Publishing Agent in Sitecore and Scheduling frequency as below.

**Publishing Agent:**

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:30">
```

**Scheduling Frequency:**

```
<scheduling>
<!-- Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute -->
<frequency>00:00:05</frequency>
```

So here you need to understand that when you set up scheduled Publish in Sitecore it considers the interval set in Publishing. But you also need to have consideration of Scheduling frequency interval which add that extra lag of 5-7 min as it is set up by you.

I was having same issue and checked with the Sitecore team itself and got the above explanation.

**Note:**

1. You can't set the schedule frequency interval to zero.
2. I will suggest a schedule considering above lag.

Comment: This is indeed the reason for the delay. But note that if this schedule is set very low, you might see a performance hit as caches will be cleared much more often as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which of the modules you use but I assume they all work in a similar way.

When you set a publishing schedule for an item, it creates a new publishing schedule task in the database under `/sitecore/system/Tasks/Schedules` node.

Then it's processed by `TaskDatabaseAgent`. And it all depends on how frequently that agent is configured to be run.

By default it's 10 minutes.

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00"/>
```

If the last time when `TaskDatabaseAgent` was executed is 6 minutes before your scheduled publishing time, it will be executed 4 minutes after your publishing scheduled time, so your item will be "late" by 4 minutes.

You can change the value of the `interval` for `"Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent"` to 10 or 30 seconds to make sure your items are published faster.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <scheduling>
      <agent name="Master_Database_Agent">
        <patch:attribute name="interval">00:00:10</patch:attribute>
      </agent>
    </scheduling>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is still taking 10 minutes to get published

Comment: I have created a config file using above text. Is there anything else i need to do?<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <scheduling>
      <agent name="Master_Database_Agent">
        <patch:attribute name="interval">00:00:10</patch:attribute>
      </agent>
    </scheduling>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>