# Schedule Publishing config

Tags: publishing

I have created a config file. but it is still taking 10 minutes to run the schedule publishing. Is there anything else i need to do?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration xmlns:patch="sitecore.net/xmlconfig" xmlns:set="sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set">
        <sitecore>
            <scheduling>
                <agent name="Master_Database_Agent">
                    <patch:attribute name="interval">00:00:10</patch:attribute>
                </agent>
            </scheduling>
        </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share your config and more info on what you actually did please?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <scheduling>
      <agent name="Master_Database_Agent">
        <patch:attribute name="interval">00:00:10</patch:attribute>
      </agent>
    </scheduling>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule publishing](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24036/schedule-publishing)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need to check the polling frequency for the agents.  The polling frequency is how often the agents are checked to see if they need to run.

Based off the time you listed, try something like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <scheduling>
            <!-- Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute -->
            <frequency>00:00:05</frequency>
        </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can find more information in [John West's post about Sitecore Scheduling](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-all-about-sitecore-scheduling-agents-and-tasks)